# Verify text - innerHTML from element using Selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, verify

Trying to verify text presence, not assert just verify

My attempt:

```
expected_footer = "© 2020 Sauce Labs. All Rights Reserved. Terms of Service | Privacy Policy"
footer_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//footer/div")
if expected_footer in footer_text:
    print("text visible...")
else:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the problem you have ?
Also, your if / else block is badly indented.

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath returns a list of web elements. You'll need to loop over them then check against the .text property of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, there will be a single footer with a webpage, so essentially instead of `find_elements*` you need to use `find_element*` and you can use the following solution:

```
expected_footer = "© 2020 Sauce Labs. All Rights Reserved. Terms of Service | Privacy Policy"
if expected_footer in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//footer/div"))).text :
    print("text visible...")
else:
    pass
```

Note: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the individual element (not the list of all elements) and then grab the text from that web element:

```
expected_footer = "© 2020 Sauce Labs. All Rights Reserved. Terms of Service | Privacy Policy"
footer_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//footer/div").text
if expected_footer in footer_text:
    print("text visible...")
else:
    pass
```

or if you want all the elements (is there more than one?)

```
expected_footer = "© 2020 Sauce Labs. All Rights Reserved. Terms of Service | Privacy Policy"
footers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//footer/div")
if expected_footer in footers[0].text:
    print("text visible...")
else:
    pass
```